# Error jquery not defined in vue component

Tags: vue.js, datatable, vuejs3

Hi I am still new to Vue JS, I am using Vue JS and trying to use Datatables from admin lte.
I already imported dist, jquery, and plugins in index.html
[image]

and I try to add the scripts for datatables like this inside a created() function

```
export default {
created(){
$(document).ready( function () {
        $.noConflict();
        $('#myTable').DataTable({
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,
            "ajax": "api/student/list",
            "columns": [
                { "data": "id" },
                { "data": "name" },
                { "data": "fatherName" },
                { "data": "rollNo" },
                { "data": "class" },
            ]
        });
 }); }}
</script>
```

but it gives an error of '$' is not defined. I already try to import the $ like this but still doesn't work

```
import $ from '../../../public/jquery/jquery.min.js';
```

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using jQuery within a Vue component. Vue handles it's internal DOM separately and jQuery access the DOM in the browser directly.